# Generate Highcharts from CSV generated by php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, csv, highcharts

I'm confused with Highcharts from csv data.

From this example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-ajax/

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=analytics.csv&callback=?', function (csv) { })
```

It can read the csv file, but when I set the url like this, it's not working

```
$.getJSON(baseurl+'webtools/analytics/submissions_data', function (csv) {
    console.log(csv);
    });
```

my server side code:

```
function submissions_data() {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    $qry = "SELECT DATE(created_date) dateonly, COUNT(id) AS total FROM mf_story GROUP BY dateonly ORDER BY dateonly ASC;";
    $rows = $this->db->query($qry)->result_array();

    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    $column = array("Day","Submissions");
    fputcsv($output, $column);

    foreach($rows as $data){
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $data['dateonly']);
        $data['dateonly'] = $date->format('n/d/Y');
        fputcsv($output, $data);
    }
}
```

And I experimented with $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url:baseurl+'webtools/analytics/submissions_data',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("data read");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow){
                console.log(jqXHR['responseText']); //the csv printed here
            }
```

And surprisingly, my csv printed in error function. Any ideas why? And what should I do to fix it? It kinda ugly to put my highcharts code in error function.

Comment: 1) What do you mean exactly by "not working"? 2) Have you verified the accuracy of your constructed URL (baseurl+'webtools/analytics/submissions_data')? What returns?  3) if you have a csv file, "jsonp" doesn't seem like the right dataType. 4) "Why?" and "How do I fix it?" Need more specific details to work with...

Comment: @jlbriggs 1) The sample from highcharts used csv right? When I changed the url to my own csv-generated, in console, didn't print anything. 2) Yes, it valid url. 4) I need help with my server side, because I can successfully get csv from http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=analytics.csv&callback=? but failed when using my server side.

Comment: Remove that line: `dataType: 'jsonp',` You are not using `jsonp` format.. That;s the only thing you didn't answer (#3) and that's the culprit why you see data in the `error()` method.

Comment: @PawełFus I found the solution, I put my csv in string and encode it with json_encode :D

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix, I changed my server side code to text/json and put csv in string

```
function submissions_data() {
    header('Content-Type: text/json');
    $qry = "SELECT DATE(created_date) dateonly, COUNT(id) AS total FROM mf_story GROUP BY dateonly ORDER BY dateonly ASC;";
    $rows = $this->db->query($qry)->result_array();

    $out = "Day,Submissions\n";

    foreach($rows as $data){
       $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $data['dateonly']);
       $data['dateonly'] = $date->format('n/d/Y');
       $out.=$data['dateonly'].",".$data['total']."\n";
    }

    echo json_encode($out);
}
```

And my json can read it, thanks :D